# Batch - pausing script until a certain system time

Tags: batch-file, time, clock, pause

I have a batchfile that I need to pause until a system time defined by the user. Here's my current script that doesn't work.

```
@echo off
echo %time%
set /p input="Enter value "
:Loop
if "%time%" == "%input%" goto Continue
GOTO Loop
:Continue
start
pause
```

Also, if possible, is there a way to simulate a media key press in batch? Would make things easier later in the process.

Comment: Please define "doesn't work" for us.

Comment: What do you `input`?  `==` relies on catching the time at the very centisecond. You might try `GEQ` instead. (Btw you shouldn't build a loop without some idle time to reduce CPU load. A simple `timeout 1>nul` should do.)

Comment: @Stephan I input the same time format as %time%, for instance "17:15:10,00".  The  usage of GEQ worked, thanks. I don't quite understand how you mean I use timeout in this case.

Comment: After `if "%time%" GEQ "%input%" goto Continue` put `timeout 1>nul`

Comment: What OS? 32 or 64-bit?  By "media key press" do you mean press a key on your keyboard?

Comment: @somebadhat Behind `if "%time%" GEQ "%input%" goto Continue put timeout 1>nul`, or on the next line? And then remove the loop? My OS is x64, and by media key press I mean any form of pausing/playing VLC mediaplayer via batch, so simulating said media key being pressed would do.

Comment: The next line.  x64 does not tell me what os you are using.  Answer my question: By "media key press" do you mean press a key on your keyboard? yes or no.

Comment: @somebadhat My bad, thought I included windows 10 in the original post, sorry. 64 bit. What's that supposed to mean, you mean if I have a robotic arm I want to press my physical keyboard? In that case, no. But the same action as if I were to press a media key? Yes.